# How do I get a summary of time in Infragistics Ultrawingrid?

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have the Infragistics UltraWinGrid in which i have a time column, hours and minutes. I want to summary the column so that I can get a total time of the trip. Each leg of the trip has its own row. I have tried:

```
Dim SumTripDuration As SummarySettings = .Summaries.Add(SummaryType.Sum, .Columns("LegDuration"), SummaryPosition.UseSummaryPositionColumn)

SumTripDuration.DisplayFormat = "{0}"
SumTripDuration.Appearance.TextHAlign = HAlign.Right
```

This doesn't work because the summary row needs to use integers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell what the type of your time column actually is, but a general solution is to create your own `ICustomSummaryCalculator` which can handle your data.

The documentation gives an [example implementation](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ICustomSummaryCalculator.html), but here's a implementation for a `TimeSpan` column:

```
Class TimeSummary
    Implements ICustomSummaryCalculator

    Dim _totals As New TimeSpan(0)
    Dim _columnname As String

    Public Sub New(columnName As String)
        _columnname = columnName
    End Sub

    Public Sub BeginCustomSummary(summarySettings As SummarySettings, rows As RowsCollection) Implements ICustomSummaryCalculator.BeginCustomSummary
        _totals  = New TimeSpan(0)
    End Sub

    Public Sub AggregateCustomSummary(summarySettings As SummarySettings, row As UltraGridRow) Implements ICustomSummaryCalculator.AggregateCustomSummary
        Dim time = row.GetCellValue(summarySettings.SourceColumn.Band.Columns(_columnname))

        If TypeOf time Is DBNull Then
            Return
        End If

        _totals += TimeSpan.Parse(time.ToString())
    End Sub

    Public Function EndCustomSummary(summarySettings As SummarySettings, rows As RowsCollection) Implements ICustomSummaryCalculator.EndCustomSummary
        Return _totals 
    End Function
End Class
```

Use it like this:

```
Dim timecolumn = grid.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("Time")
grid.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Summaries.Add(SummaryType.Custom, New TimeSummary(timecolumn.Key), timecolumn, SummaryPosition.UseSummaryPositionColumn, timecolumn)
```

Comment: The time column comes from the database Time(7) datatype.

Comment: @Helmbo I've added an example of how to handle TimeSpans